# Mapbox featureLayer won't show

Tags: javascript, mapbox

So, I have a Mapbox map, and I'm looping through an array to generate the array of geojson objects. I have some methods I've abstracted out-- I've tested everything and it all works, but my markers aren't showing. What am I doing wrong?

`var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'my_map_code_thing');`
`var geojson = [];`

`var layer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);`

`for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  var marker =
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          myArray[i].latitude,
          myArray[i].longitude
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": myArray[i].title,
        "address": myArray[i].address,
        "marker-color": getColor(myArray[i].price_low),
        "marker-size": "medium",
        "marker-symbol": getSymbol(myArray[i].genre)
      }
    }
    geojson.push(marker);
  };`

  `layer.setGeoJSON(geojson);
   layer.on('ready', function() {
     map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
  });`

Answer (score 2):

I just tried running your code and it works fine. The code I tried is :

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'my_map_code_thing');
var layer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
var myArray= [
{
    "latitude": -77.03238901390978,
    "longitude": 38.913188059745586
},
{
    "latitude": -122.414,
    "longitude": 37.776
}
];
var geojson = [];
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

var marker = {
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [
  myArray[i].latitude,
  myArray[i].longitude
  ]
},
"properties": {
  "title": "Mapbox DC",
  "description": "1714 14th St NW, Washington DC",
  "marker-color": "#fc4353",
  "marker-size": "large",
  "marker-symbol": "monument"
}
}
geojson.push(marker);
}

layer.setGeoJSON(geojson);
layer.on('ready', function() {
 map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
});
```

Just make sure that you are getting the correct values of `latitude`, `longitude` and other `properties` from `myArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `layer.geoJSON(geojson);` instead of `layer.setGeoJSON(geojson);`

Comment: Hrmm... no dice. It gives me: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

I believe I was running into [this problem](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson.io/issues/289). On a fluke I accidentally zoomed out and saw I was generating a marker in Antarctica. Reversed the lat/lng and everything was fine.